# which() does not work for some numbers

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where the first column consists of the numbers 0,0.01,...,0.99,1. Using the which() function i'm trying to find the row indices that contain a certain set of numbers in the first three columns. Peculiarly, this does  does not work for the numbers 0.35, 0.41, 0.47, 0.57, 0.69, 0.70, 0.82, 0.83, 0.94 and 0.95 in the first column. I'm sure they exist in the data frame, but which() returns integer(0) each time. Can anybody help?

```
StateIndex = function(state)
{
  state = as.numeric(state)
  aux = which(states[,colnames(states)[1]] == state[1])
  for (i in 2:3)
  {
    aux = aux[which(states[aux,colnames(states)[i]] == state[i])]
  }
return(aux)
}

states = list()
states[[1]] = seq(0,1,by=1/M) #zeta1 at last action
states[[2]] = 1:(m+1)         #i (last observed det. level)
states[[3]] = 0:N             #j (time since last action)

states = expand.grid(states)

nstates = dim(states)[1]
```

Comment: are you sure it's exactly `0.35`, not, e.g., `0.3500000000000001`?

Comment: Yes, i added the data frame for clarity. The first column contains the numbers 0 to 1 with steps of 1/100.

Comment: search on stackoverfelow for question first then ask.

Comment: I did. I already tried isTRUE(all.equal()). Sorry I did not mention that.

Comment: Can you clarify your data set? What are `M`, `m`, and `N`? Ideally, provide code and data that can simply be copy and pasted to reproduce your error.

Comment: Try `sprintf('%.100f', states$Var1[23313])` and you will see it's not 0.82 :)